# how to calculate minutes between 2 datetime

Tags: clips

I am trying to implement a def function that should calculate minutes between 2 datetime ,

How can I implement?

"date1": "2020-04-17T20:45:00.000Z"

"date2": "2020-04-17T20:25:00.000Z"

should be
output: 20

Ideally, I would like to convert these datetime values to a second-based repsresentation, such as unixtime, so that I can do the math via simple substraction.

Comment: @Gary Riley if you have time ,please can you look at this.

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49794285/clips-compare-2-dates/49835160#49835160 to an example of pulling date/time components from a string